# MySQL config file location - redhat linux server

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

What is the default location for the MySQL configuration file on a redhat linux box?

Answer (score 58):

Just found it, it is /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 48):

The information you want can be found by running

```
mysql --help
```

or

```
mysqld --help --verbose
```

I tried this :

```
    mysql --help | grep Default -A 1
```

And the output:

```
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash 
--
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to disable.)
  -L, --skip-line-numbers 
--
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-column-names to disable.)
  -N, --skip-column-names 
--
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)
  -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
--
  --default-auth=name Default authentication client-side plugin to use.
  --binary-mode       By default, ASCII '\0' is disallowed and '\r\n' is
--
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Comment: For me `/usr/libexec/mysqld --help --verbose` worked instead of `mysqld --help --verbose`

Comment: @Andron yes if the path to executable daemon is not in the ENV PATH, you will have to specify the absolute path to the daemon executable.

Answer (score 21):

it is located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: This is default on debian based distros, but not valid for RedHat.

Answer (score 8):

All of them seemed good candidates:

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf
...
```

in many cases you could simply check system process list using ps:

```
server ~ # ps ax | grep '[m]ysqld'
```

Output

```
10801 ?        Ssl    0:27 /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Or

```
which mysqld
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Then

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"

/etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 5):

On RH systems, MySQL configuration file is located under /etc/my.cnf by default.

Answer (score 5):

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf 
/etc/my.cnf 
~/.my.cnf
```

Answer (score 3):

In the docker containers(centos based images) it is located at

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

From the header of '/etc/mysql/my.cnf':

```
MariaDB programs look for option files in a set of
locations which depend on the deployment platform.
[...] For information about these locations, do:
'my_print_defaults --help' and see what is printed under
"Default options are read from the following files in the given order:"
More information at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
```